# How to send hidden link from bot

Tags: botframework, bots

I need to redirect user. User sends message: "show me my profile", bot sends hidden link and redirect him to profile page.

Now I'm doing it with backchannel:

```
botConnection.activity$
    .subscribe(activity => redirect(activity.value))
```

But that means, that user can see message with link from bot and only after that user will be redirected. How can I hide this message from user?

Answer (score 2):

> I need to redirect user. User sends message: "show me my profile", bot sends hidden link and redirect him to profile page.

As you mentioned, the [backchannel mechanism](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#the-backchannel) can help exchange information between client and bot without presenting it to the user by setting the activity type to `event`. You can refer to the following code snippet to achieve your requirement.

*In bot dialog:*

```
if(activity.Text.ToLower() == "show me my profile")
{
    var reply = context.MakeMessage() as IEventActivity;
    reply.Type = "event";
    reply.Name = "showprofile";

    //store the url of user profile in Value property
    reply.Value = $"{profile_url}";

    await context.PostAsync((IMessageActivity)reply);
}
```

*On webchat client:*

```
//listens for "showprofile" event from the bot

botConnection.activity$
    .filter(activity => activity.type === "event" && activity.name === "showprofile")
    .subscribe(activity => showmyprofile(activity.value));

function showmyprofile(profile_url) {
    window.open(profile_url);
}
```